# What would you do when there are too many roles in the access token?

Tags: authorization, keycloak, roles, rbac

Too many roles in the token increases the header size of every HTTP request. On the other hand, if the roles are totally removed from the token, and are to be obtained from yet another API call, it would cause increased latency.

Can a distributed cache help in this matter? The API gateway would somehow fetch the roles and populate all other cache replicas with the roles before the API call is forwarded to the application

Are there any better battle tested design-pattern-ish solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> if the roles are totally removed from the token, and are to be obtained from yet another API call, it would cause increased latency.

If that API is designed to be fast, then the increased latency would not be a lot.

Fine-grained permissions can be a solution to the role explosion problem that you mentioned. See https://auth0.com/blog/supercharge-your-authorization-system-with-openfga/.

Disclaimer: I am part of the Auth0 team building OpenFGA.

Answer (score -1):

You are describing a very common downfall of RBAC called "role explosion." The fastest, easiest way to fix this and increase your security posture is by adding fine-gained permissions to your app.

You also mentioned latency. Check out [Aserto.com](https://www.aserto.com). It's a fine-grained authorization system with a distributed systems architecture for blazing fast access controls.